# QApplication segfaults in Googletest

Tags: qt, qt4, googletest

I have two Googletest that call QApplication. When I run the tests the second test throws a `Segmentation fault`. Adding `app.quit()` or `.exit(0)` didn't help.
What did help but what I don't want to do is constructing `QApplication app(argc, argv, false)`, which sets `GuiEnabled = false`.

Any ideas on what to do? Below is code that shows this behaviour.

MWE:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include <QtGui/QApplication>

TEST(Foo, empty) {
  char** argv;
  int argc = 0;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  app.quit();
}

TEST(Foo, empty2) {
  char** argv;
  int argc = 0;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  app.quit();
}
```

This is in Qt4, Googletest 1.6.0.

Comment: Why do you need to create QApplication in each of your tests? It initializes a lot of statics and isn't designed to be constructed multiple times in the same process.

Comment: Why would app.quit() help if you didn't execute application?

Comment: I think multiple constructions of QApplication might be the problem, does that work  anyway? I would construct one QApplication and use that in your tests as a fixture.